# Weight selection for extrinsic in case of multiple bechmarks

Tags: weight, benchmarking

In my benchmarks, I've written multiple benchmarks for an extrinsic to cover different scenarios, which gave me WeightIinfo for each of my benchmarks.

Now the question here is how I can pick the worst scenario for my extrinsic dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!
The `#[pallet::weight(…)]` annotation allows you to do some light compile-time computations.
This makes it possible to calculate a maximum like this:

```rust
#[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::slow().max(T::WeightInfo::slower()))]
```

One example of this can be found in the [bags-list pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b0777b4c7f7d8d3c635319d0153953d0a22aa58e/frame/bags-list/src/lib.rs#L224).
It is important to only do very lightweight calculations here, since the terms are evaluated to judge whether or not an extrinsic should be able to execute.
I think the most complicated weight terms are in the [utility pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b0777b4c7f7d8d3c635319d0153953d0a22aa58e/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L300).